# Add a Widget to Tableau Dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

Good Morning,

I have been asked to add see if we can add a weather widget to a Tableau Dashboard.  I have attached a picture of what they want.  It unfortunately has to look just like this,  any suggestions on if this is possible and how to do it.

[image: Weather Widget]

I am utilizing Tableau 10.1.

Thanks,

Comment: is it a image or an interactive widget?

Comment: It's an image but with all data updated.

Comment: you can add the image in a dashboard, create the image and then add that in dashboard, This should help you

Comment: Yes this is possible. How is the data that feeds viz structured? You have both forecast data and current conditions, so you might have at least 2 sources. What do the numbers in the top right represent? expected high/low for the day?

Comment: How is the widget hosted ? i.e. website ?

Comment: In order to get what we are looking for, it is not currently possible in Tableau.  We just wanted to plug the wizard in- like the app on our phones..  I could recreate it manually but too much work for what we want.